# Is $\aleph_1= \aleph_0+1 $ wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My understanding is that any cardinality is always an integer because it expresses how many elements are in a given set. And I read that $\aleph_1$ is the next smallest cardinality that's larger than $\aleph_0$, so it seems to me that $\aleph_1 = \aleph_0+1$. However I don't see this equation anywhere on the Internet so I guess I'm wrong. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Only the finite cardinalities are (nonnegative) integers; the rest are, well, cardinals, which are different. $\aleph_0 + 1$ is just $\aleph_0$ again.

Comment: What is true is that $\aleph_1=\aleph_{0+1}$.

Comment: $\aleph_{0+1}=\aleph_1\gt\aleph_0=\aleph_0+1.$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there a special symbol or something to express the value of  $\aleph_1$ - $\aleph_0$?

Comment: @stacko: to the extent that that makes sense, that's just $\aleph_1$ again.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is $\aleph_1$ smaller than  $|\mathbb {R}|$?

Comment: @stacko this is independent of $ZFC$(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong part is that you took what you know about finite cardinals and extend it to infinite ones.

Assuming choice $\aleph_0$ is the smallest cardinal that is greater than all the finite cardinal, the first limit ordinal. To advance to $\aleph_1$ we need to find a set such that there is no injective from $A$ to $\Bbb N$, but $\aleph_0+1=|\Bbb N\cup\{0\}|=|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0$.

Even more: for $\kappa,\nu$  cardinals such that one of them is infinite we have $\kappa+\nu=\kappa\cdot\nu=\max\{\kappa,\nu\}$

Comment: @Arthur yes, but it is not the smallest without it

Comment: We only need countable choice for $\aleph_0$ to be the smallest infinite ordinal (and I think it's minimal regardless), but fair enough. We do need choice for $\max$ to be well-defined, though.

Comment: @Arthur indeed even without choice every infinite cardinal is either not comparable or greater equal to $\aleph_0$